# Parsing Multiple XML Files to one CSV

Tags: python, xml, csv

I have a db with 1000's of xml files. In order for a proof of concept I need to parse about 20 xml files and save into one csv file. I keep overwriting the files and my current output in the csv is only the last xml file. Here is my current code.

```
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

 with open(r'C:\Users\akeske\Desktop\clinical.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
       writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

 file_id=1;
 for path, dirs, files in os.walk(r"X:\Clinical Data R&D\Adam Keske\CCD\Unzipped"):
    for f in files:
        clinical = os.path.join(path, f)
        print(clinical)
        tree = ET.parse(clinical)
        root = tree.getroot()

 for child in root.iter():
    key = child.tag
    value = child.text
    writer.writerow([key, value])
    file_id+=1
```

Comment: Please fix indentation. As of now, posted code should raise errors.

Comment: I presume that even if your code was properly indented, you'd have problems? Your code as-is doesn't run, `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`, because `writer` is being used _outside_ of its `with` context.

Comment: The code was properly indented it was a copying error. Also does anyone know how to attach a record id or file name that is attached as each file is passed through?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open(r"C:\Users\akeske\Desktop\clinical.csv", "w", newline="") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    file_id = 1
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(r"X:\Clinical Data R&D\Adam Keske\CCD\Unzipped"):
        for f in files:
            clinical = os.path.join(path, f)
            print(clinical)
            tree = ET.parse(clinical)
            root = tree.getroot()

            for child in root.iter():
                key = child.tag
                value = child.text
                writer.writerow([key, value])
            file_id += 1
```

Comment: It helps alot! I have a follow up question. How do I add a record key or the file name to this so every time that a new file is passed through it attaches the record key\ file name in the csv